# when I click a file upload so popup is open and website is exit from the full screen?

Tags: reactjs

I have already used full screen functionality but the problem is this if My website is on full screen but I am clicking the file upload option so dialog box is open and at the time my website is going to the exit full screen. I don't want to exit full screen.

```
 const getFullscreenElement = () => {
    return document.fullscreenElement
      || document.webkitFullscreenElement
      || document.mozFullscreenElement
      || document.msFullscreenElement
  }
 
  const toggleFullscreen = () => {
    if (getFullscreenElement()) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
      setIsFullscreen(false)
    } else {
      setIsFullscreen(true)
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen().catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }

{!isFullscreen ? (
              <CssIconButton
                size='large'
                aria-label='show 4 new mails'
                title='Full Screen'
                onClick={toggleFullscreen}
              >
                <FullscreenIcon />
              </CssIconButton>
            ) : (
              <CssIconButton
                size='large'
                aria-label='show 4 new mails'
                title='Exit Full Screen'
                onClick={toggleFullscreen}
              >
                <FullscreenExitIcon />
              </CssIconButton>
            )
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried how this on other websites? Maybe it's due to how the browser/OS works?

Comment: yes I have tried but it is showing same

Comment: Showing same as in works like on your website? Cause in that case it could be that you can't work around it

Comment: yes it is working on mozila browser and not working on crome and edge browser.